# Exclude value from foreach loop output

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am looking to exclude a specific value from my `foreach` output where it occurs in either `friend_one` or `friend_two`. I do not want to exclude this from my query.

The parameter to exclude would be `$profile_user` where it occurs in either `friend_one` or `friend_two`. I tried to do this `if(in_array($friend_total_row->friend_one == $profile_user))`, but I am getting errors with it, plus it only has `friend_one` in it.

Anyone have an idea how I can do this?

```
<?php           
    //Friends --- total
    $friend_status = 2;
    $friend_sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM friends
        WHERE (friend_one = :profile_user or friend_two = :profile_user)
        AND status = :total_status
    ";
    $friend_stmt = $con->prepare($friend_sql);
    $friend_stmt->execute(array(':profile_user' => $profile_user, ':total_status' => $friend_status));
    $friend_total_rows = $friend_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $count_total_friend = $friend_stmt->rowCount();
?>  
        <div id="friend-list-container">
            <div id="friend-list-count">Friends <span class="light-gray"><?php echo $count_total_friend; ?></span></div>
            <div id="friend-list-image-container">
<?php           
    foreach ($friend_total_rows as $friend_total_row) {
        if(in_array($friend_total_row->friend_one == $profile_user)) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
        $friend_1   = $friend_total_row['friend_one'];
        $friend_2   = $friend_total_row['friend_two'];
        //$friend_status        = $friend_total_row['status'];
        //$friend_status_date = $friend_total_row['date'];
        }
        echo $friend_1 . $friend_2;
    }
?>
```

I am only wanting to exclude the `$profile_user` from outputting, which is where the X is. Then I want the squared output to show.
[image]

Comment: this line `if(in_array($friend_total_row->friend_one == $profile_user))` is wrong. you have to separate by comma, not two equal signs. http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Just to ask why do you not want to exclude this in the query. Also, with the current setup you would be getting duplicate rows on the instance that the friend is profile is that something you expect?

Comment: @nerdlyist I do not want to exclude from the query because the query is matching relationships. IE: If the profile user is in the same record with another user, that is a friendship. Within this output, I am wanting to exclude the profile user to simply show their friends.

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer :

```
foreach ($friend_total_rows as $friend_total_row) {
    $friend_1   = $friend_total_row['friend_one'];
    $friend_2   = $friend_total_row['friend_two'];

    if($friend_1 !== $profile_user) {
        echo $friend_1;
    }

    if($friend_2 !== $profile_user) {
        echo $friend_2;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first example you gave is giving errors for `->` and the second, `in_array` example is giving `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in` errors.

Comment: For array - `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$friend_total_row' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ']` ... the comparison is not giving errors for the brackets `[` as well.

Comment: hmmm.. no longer any errors, but it is not outputting anything. Does this exclude the entire row from outputting? I am only wanting to exclude the `$profile_user` from outputting. I added an image to help understand.

Comment: Humm.. Just understood what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Sorry if my question wasn't very clear. Do you know if there is a function that could randomize the results? I can look it up, just do not know if there is or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129274/discussion-between-max-and-paul).

Comment: @nerdlyist Actually he wanted to display either `$friend_1` or `$friend_2`, not hide the whole thing

Comment: @nerdlyist Come on.. OP gave details as he went along.. And my answer begins with "Updated answer". This is not as if it was some kind of complex algorithm that you only have the hability to conceive.